# Excel formulas return #VALUE! error after changes are made

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet where multiple cells have a variation of a `SUMIFS` formula. The cells were working fine until I decided to make a few changes to the calculations. I noticed that each time I made a change and moved on I would get a `#VALUE!` error. It even happened when I simply picked the formula cell and pressed enter. How do I remedy this issue?

My formula:
`=SUMIFS(I36:I93,R36:R93,"=4",U36:U93,"DF STUD 92 1/4",V36:V93,"STUDS")`

Comment: Show some data to explain what you see, then perhaps we may be able to comment / answer.

Comment: please share the formula and a sample of the data so we might be able to help

Comment: I added formula, the data is just a bunch of random numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
+sumfis(I36,I93,R36:R93,4,U36:U93,"DF STUD 92 1/4",V36:V93,"STUDS")
```

When looking up a value that you want equal to a number, you do not need quotation marks and an equal sign, you simply put the number in the formula.  See if the above works/helps.